# Too many UCP Timer threads

Tags: jdbc, ucp

I am using Oracle UCP 12.1.0.2.0. Overtime, it is starting too many Timer threads and eventually causing Out Of Memory error in JVM. 
Is there any fix or configuration change that I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue which was recently resolved in the soon-to-be-released 12.2 version. The bug number is 21187539. If you have access to the MOS page (My Oracle Support) then you should be able to request the patch for 12.1.0.2. I hope this helps. Regards.